# EM noise from Peltier cooler

Tags: noise, emc, peltier

I'm considering cooling a very sensitive photodetector with a Peltier module.
I have been told by a colleague Peltiers coolers produce electromagnetic noise, but I am wondering whether this is due to the Peltier device itself or rather a consequence of using PWM to power/control it, or the hot side fan motor.

If one was to use an adjustable linear regulator, and smooth out any step introduced by the control loop, the current flowing through the device would be ~constant in the steady state.

Would the Peltier device itself still generate EM noise in this configuration? If yes, by which mechanism?

Is there any frequency band that would be more affected?

Our preamp has a significant bandwidth and our sensor has a small signal, so any noise is potentially problematic.

Comment: As heat flow and electron flow (current) are both ultimately statistics, the answer has to be yes at some level. Enough to detect on an electrically isolated detector? Don't know. Current leads to a predictable magnitude of shot noise in the Peltier itself, you'll have to model the attenuation between it and detector.

Comment: I think they are most likely referring to the current noise generated by the driver (probably in the context of PWM control).  Since TECs can be run at very high currents and are generally very close to the sensor they are cooling, noise on the power supply could be an issue.

Comment: if this is a really sensitive project, PWMing a Peltier cooler also introduces *thermal* noise (as in, the temperature goes up and down, obviously). It also wastes power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peltier won't produce electromagnetic noise necessarily but the PWM will, which at a closest approximation is like a square wave. Ttherfore the fundamental frequency of the square wave will determine most noise that you see and it can show up in many places, even analog electronics.

The EM noise will be both RF and magnetic, RF from capacitance between the cable\peliter and everything else. Magnetic from the current.

If you do run PWM, you'll need to have proper shielding techniques (shielded cable, ferrites, ect). In addition, the PWM noise can be conducted because of the power being switched and bleed into analog electronics if they are on the same supply.

I have built both types of systems (PWM and voltage controlled peliters) I would suggest to leave the headache out of it if you can and run a voltage controlled scheme with a high current amplifier and a DAC (sometimes higher powers above 2A can be hard to achieve with voltage controlled peliters and only PWM will suffice). A voltage controlled scheme should be used if the power is in the 100mA range and you have sensitive electronics.